# Access Web Methods from multiple aspx pages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I have a user control which is used in multiple(4 to be exact) aspx pages. This usercontrol have a couple of Get/Save webmethods. Right now, I placed all the webmethods in one aspx page and kept calling the same ones from my javascript. I would like to place them in a central location that all the aspx pages can see, but not sure how/where. Any suggestions please?

Edit:
I know the WebMethods should be a part of a class inherited from 'System.Web.UI.Page'. Is there a better place that I can move these methods to, where js can call from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. try to creating Generic Handler (.ahx) and put all your code there.
> 2. or try to creating base page, where the base page inherited with the all the aspx pages

**in your aspx page :**

```
public partial class RekapDocumentView : based.PageBase
{

}
```

**in your new class :**

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   //your webmethods
}
```

perhaps this can help

Comment: This sounds like a better way to design for this project. I might go with this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create a class, VS will ask you if you wont to create a folder for it. All common classes should go in App_code folder. Then you can move your method in that class and reference them from the pages.

Comment: Oh can we make a call to .cs class from js ajax postback like 
  $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "JSON",
   url: "/Pages/Employee/EmployeeMethods.cs/SaveEmployee",
   data: "{ NoteDTO: " + JSON.stringify(NoteToSave) + "}" ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499952/calling-a-class-method-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: this is my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19777020/accessing-web-method-declared-in-cs-file-not-associated-to-any-aspx-or-ascx-fil

Comment: Ok. What do you mean? You got the solution?

Comment: Nope, not yet. But, this guy has the same problem as me. I dont think theres an exact answer here.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a web service which implements web methods that your user control needs to work properly.

Here is a MSDN article on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515101(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros

Comment: I am not sure If we can use a webservice for this project. I need to discuss with my team. Thanks for the idea.